# Преобразование апплета в приложение java

Tags: java, swing, applet, awt

Вообщем я написал апплет-игру "Крестики-нолики"(за основу взял код с книги Файна) и у меня возникло желание преобразовать апплет в приложение java, что бы потом сделать Jar-овский файлик и автономно его запускать на компе. Вот код:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.applet.Applet;


public class TicTacToe extends Applet implements ActionListener{ 
    Button squares[];
    Button newGameButton;
    Label score;

    Label results1;
    Label results2;

    int emptySquaresLeft=9;
    int Win = 0;
    int Lost = 0;

    /**
     * Метод init – это конструктор апплета
     */

    public void init(){

//Устанавливаем менеджер расположения апплета, шрифт и цвет

        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.setBackground(Color.CYAN);

// Изменяем шрифт апплета так, чтобы он был жирным
// и имел размер 20

        Font appletFont=new Font("Monospased",Font.BOLD, 20);
        this.setFont(appletFont);

// Создаем кнопку “New Game” и регистрируем в ней
// слушатель действия

        newGameButton=new Button("New Game");
        newGameButton.addActionListener(this);
        Panel topPanel=new Panel();

        results1 = new Label("Wins: "+Win);
        results2 = new Label("  Losts: "+Lost);
        topPanel.add(results1);

        topPanel.add(newGameButton);

        topPanel.add(results2);

        this.add(topPanel,"North");
        Panel centerPanel=new Panel();
        centerPanel.setLayout(new  GridLayout(3,3));
        this.add(centerPanel,"Center");

        score=new Label("Your turn!");
        this.add(score,"South");

// создаем массив, чтобы хранить ссылки на 9 кнопок

        squares=new Button[9];

// Создаем кнопки, сохраняем ссылки на них в массиве
// регистрируем в них слушатель, красим их
// в оранжевый цвет и добавляем на панель
        for(int i=0;i<9;i++){ squares[i]=new Button();
            squares[i].addActionListener(this);
            squares[i].setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
            centerPanel.add(squares[i]);

        }
    }



    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { Button theButton = (Button) e.getSource();
// Это кнопка New Game ?

        if (theButton ==newGameButton){

            for(int i=0;i<9;i++){

                squares[i].setEnabled(true); squares[i].setLabel(""); squares[i].setBackground(Color.ORANGE);

            }

            emptySquaresLeft=9; score.setText("Your turn!"); newGameButton.setEnabled(false);

            return; // выходим из метода
        }

        String winner = "";

// Это одна из клеток?

        for ( int i=0; i<9; i++ ) {

            if (  theButton == squares[i] ) {

                squares[i].setLabel("X");
                Test();
                winner = lookForWinner();

                if(!"".equals(winner)){
                    endTheGame();
                } else {

                    computerMove();
                    Test();
                    winner = lookForWinner();

                    if ( !"".equals(winner)){
                        endTheGame();
                    }
                }

                break;
            }
        } // конец цикла for

        if ( winner.equals("X") ) {
            score.setText("You won!");
            Win++;
            results1.setText("Wins: "+Win);

        } else if (winner.equals("O")){
            score.setText("You lost!");
            Lost++;
            results2.setText("  Losts: "+Lost);

        } else if (winner.equals("T")){
            score.setText("It's a tie!");

        }
    } // конец метода actionPerformed

    /**
     *   Этот метод вызывается после каждого хода, чтобы узнать,
     *   есть ли победитель. Он проверяет каждый ряд, колонку
     *   и диагональ, чтобы найти три клетки с одинаковыми надписями
     *   (не пустыми)
     *   @return "X", "O", "T" – ничья, "" - еще нет победителя
     */

    String lookForWinner() {

        String theWinner = ""; emptySquaresLeft--;


        if (emptySquaresLeft==0){
            return "T"; // это ничья. T от английского слова tie

        }

// Проверяем ряд 1 – элементы массива 0,1,2
        if (!squares[0].getLabel().equals("") &&

                squares[0].getLabel().equals(squares[1].getLabel())  && squares[0].getLabel().equals(squares[2].getLabel()))  {

            theWinner = squares[0].getLabel(); highlightWinner(0,1,2);

// Проверяем ряд 2 – элементы массива 3,4,5
        } else if (!squares[3].getLabel().equals("")    &&

                squares[3].getLabel().equals(squares[4].getLabel())  && squares[3].getLabel().equals(squares[5].getLabel()))  {

            theWinner = squares[3].getLabel(); highlightWinner(3,4,5);

// Проверяем ряд 3 – элементы массива 6,7,8
        } else if ( ! squares[6].getLabel().equals("") &&

                squares[6].getLabel().equals(squares[7].getLabel())  && squares[6].getLabel().equals(squares[8].getLabel()))  {

            theWinner = squares[6].getLabel(); highlightWinner(6,7,8);

// Проверяем колонку 1 – элементы массива 0,3,6
        } else if ( ! squares[0].getLabel().equals("") &&

                squares[0].getLabel().equals(squares[3].getLabel())  && squares[0].getLabel().equals(squares[6].getLabel()))  {

            theWinner = squares[0].getLabel(); highlightWinner(0,3,6);

// Проверяем колонку 2 – элементы массива 1,4,7
        } else if ( ! squares[1].getLabel().equals("") &&

                squares[1].getLabel().equals(squares[4].getLabel())  && squares[1].getLabel().equals(squares[7].getLabel()))  {

            theWinner = squares[1].getLabel(); highlightWinner(1,4,7);

// Проверяем колонку 3 – элементы массива 2,5,8
        } else if ( ! squares[2].getLabel().equals("") &&

                squares[2].getLabel().equals(squares[5].getLabel())  && squares[2].getLabel().equals(squares[8].getLabel()))  {

            theWinner = squares[2].getLabel(); highlightWinner(2,5,8);

// Проверяем первую диагональ – элементы массива 0,4,8

        } else if ( ! squares[0].getLabel().equals("") &&

                squares[0].getLabel().equals(squares[4].getLabel())  && squares[0].getLabel().equals(squares[8].getLabel()))  {

            theWinner = squares[0].getLabel(); highlightWinner(0,4,8);

// Проверяем вторую диагональ – элементы массива 2,4,6
        } else if ( ! squares[2].getLabel().equals("") &&

                squares[2].getLabel().equals(squares[4].getLabel())  && squares[2].getLabel().equals(squares[6].getLabel()))  {

            theWinner = squares[2].getLabel(); highlightWinner(2,4,6);
        }

        return theWinner;

    }

    /**
     *   Этот метод применяет набор правил, чтобы найти
     *   лучший компьютерный ход. Если хороший ход
     *   не найден, выбирается случайная клетка.
     */

    void computerMove() {

        int selectedSquare;

// Сначала компьютер пытается найти пустую клетку
// рядом с двумя клетками с ноликами, чтобы выиграть

        selectedSquare = findEmptySquare("O");

// Если он не может найти два нолика, то хотя бы
// попытается не дать оппоненту сделать ряд из 3-х
// крестиков,поместив нолик рядом с двумя крестиками
        if ( selectedSquare == -1 )

            selectedSquare =    findEmptySquare("X");


    if((selectedSquare == -1)&&(squares[4].getLabel().equals(""))){
        selectedSquare=4;
    }

// не повезло с центральной клеткой...
// просто занимаем случайную клетку
    if(selectedSquare == -1){
        selectedSquare = getRandomSquare();
    }

    squares[selectedSquare].setLabel("O");
}


    int findEmptySquare(String player) {

        int weight[] = new int[9];

        for ( int i = 0; i < 9; i++ ) {

            if ( squares[i].getLabel().equals("O") ) weight[i] = -1;
            else if ( squares[i].getLabel().equals("X") ) weight[i] = 1;
            else
                weight[i] = 0;
        }

        int twoWeights = player.equals("O") ? -2 : 2;

// Проверим, есть ли в ряду 1 две одинаковые клетки и
// одна пустая.
        if ( weight[0] + weight[1] + weight[2] == twoWeights ) {
            if ( weight[0] == 0 )
                return 0;
            else if ( weight[1] == 0 )
                return 1;
            else
                return 2;
        }

// Проверим, есть ли в ряду 2 две одинаковые клетки и
// одна пустая.
        if (weight[3] +weight[4] + weight[5] == twoWeights) {
            if ( weight[3] == 0 )
                return 3;
            else if ( weight[4] == 0 )
                return 4;
            else
                return 5;
        }


// Проверим, есть ли в ряду 3 две одинаковые клетки и
// одна пустая.
        if (weight[6] + weight[7] +weight[8] == twoWeights ) {

            if ( weight[6] == 0 )
                return 6;
            else if ( weight[7] == 0 )
                return 7;
            else
                return 8;
        }

// Проверим, есть ли в колонке 1 две одинаковые клетки и
// одна пустая.
        if (weight[0] + weight[3] + weight[6] == twoWeights) {

            if ( weight[0] == 0 )
                return 0;
            else if ( weight[3] == 0 )
                return 3;
            else
                return 6;
        }

// Проверим, есть ли в колонке 2 две одинаковые клетки
// и одна пустая.
        if (weight[1] +weight[4] + weight[7] == twoWeights ) {

            if ( weight[1] == 0 )
                return 1;
            else if ( weight[4] == 0 )
                return 4;
            else
                return 7;
        }

// Проверим, есть ли в колонке 3 две одинаковые клетки
// и одна пустая.
        if (weight[2] + weight[5] + weight[8] == twoWeights ){

            if ( weight[2] == 0 )
                return 2;
            else if ( weight[5] == 0 )
                return 5;
            else
                return 8;

        }

// Проверим, есть ли в диагонали 1 две одинаковые клетки
// и одна пустая.
        if (weight[0] + weight[4] + weight[8] == twoWeights ){

            if ( weight[0] == 0 )
                return 0;
            else if ( weight[4] == 0 )
                return 4;
            else
                return 8;
        }

// Проверим, есть ли в диагонали 2 две одинаковые клетки
// и одна пустая.
        if (weight[2] + weight[4] + weight[6] == twoWeights ){

            if ( weight[2] == 0 )
                return 2;
            else if ( weight[4] == 0 )
                return 4;
            else
                return 6;
        }

// Не найдено двух одинаковых соседних клеток
        return -1;

    } // конец метода findEmptySquare()

    /**
     *   Этот метод выбирает любую пустую клетку
     *   @return случайно выбранный номер клетки
     */

    int getRandomSquare() {

        boolean gotEmptySquare = false; int selectedSquare = -1;
        do {

            selectedSquare = (int) (Math.random() * 9 );

            if  (squares[selectedSquare].getLabel().equals("")){ gotEmptySquare = true; // чтобы закончить цикл
            }

        } while (!gotEmptySquare );

        return selectedSquare;

    } // конец метода getRandomSquare()


    void highlightWinner(int win1, int win2, int win3) {

        squares[win1].setBackground(Color.CYAN); squares[win2].setBackground(Color.CYAN); squares[win3].setBackground(Color.CYAN);
    }

    // Делаем недоступными клетки и доступной кнопку ”New Game”
    void endTheGame(){ newGameButton.setEnabled(true); for(int i=0;i<9;i++){
        squares[i].setEnabled(false);

    }
    }

    //Ф-ция для запрета нажатия на 1 и ту-же клетку по нескольку раз 
    void Test(){

        for(int i=0;i<9;i++){

            if(squares[i].getLabel().equals("O") || squares[i].getLabel().equals("X")) {
                squares[i].setEnabled(false);
                squares[i].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Насколько я понимаю для преобразования апплета мне необходимо перестать наследовать класс `TicTacToe` от класса `Applet`, из ф-ции `init()` сделать конструктор, добавить класс `main()`, в нем создать объект класса `TicTacToe`, и после этого вызывать от-туда вызывать необходимые мне ф-ции.

К примеру я пытался вызвать ф-цию `actionPerfomed`, ну это понятное дело не получилось, поскольку туда передается параметр `ActionEvent e`, который необходим для получения информации о кнопках на которые я нажимаю. И кроме этого придется еще сделать все другие методы и переменные статическими.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как же все-таки правильно преобразовать апплет в приложение, возможно есть какие-то другие варианты по преобразованию?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться тем, что `Applet` - это наследник `java.awt.Component`, и его можно вставить в awt/swing контейнеры, например `JFrame` (класс, создающий окно).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame(); // выбран JFrame, т.к. у него можно задать поведение
                                 // при закрытии
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );

    TicTacToe game = new TicTacToe();
    game.init(); // нужно вызвать init() самостоятельно (либо создать конструктор
                 // и вызвать в нем)
    frame.setContentPane( game ); // устанавливаем в качестве основной панели фрейма

    frame.pack(); // сообщаем фрейму, чтобы он установил размеры исходя из содержимого
                  // можно задать самому, через .setSize()
    frame.setVisible( true );
}
```

`actionPerformed` вам самому вызывать не надо, она по-прежнему будет вызывать при нажатии на кнопки, у которых ваш класс зарегистрирован, как слушатель (через `addActionListener`).

Делать что-то статическими методами тоже нет необходимости, т.к. и так создается объект `TicTacToe`.

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь!